# how to perform group by and sum on dataframe . I have a Dataframe1 I want to convert into Dataframe2 like this

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a given Dataframe df1 .

[image]

---

I want to convert it into Dataframe like below. How to do so?? Thanks in advance

### [image]

I tried this 
df1=df.groupby(['MONTH','STORECODE']).apply(lambda x: list((x.VALUE)))

and got this:

MONTH   |  STORECODE
M1      |   N5      |[175.0]
M2      |   N5      |[235.0, 71.0]

Comment: Can you please give us which code have you tried before asking? Also, how do you get bill_ids and bill_amt?

Comment: @JonathanSánchez Hope its clear now

Comment: whats the logic behind the sum column? and can you paste your data as text and not image.

Comment: @Datanovice so for every month in every store we are calculating the total sales made for each kind of products( MILK Foods and Spice here)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this approach:

```
df1.groupby(['Month', 'StoreCode'], as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
```

It returns a new DF with three colums: `Month, StoreCode & Sum` which are the only uniques ones if I understood correctly.

Note: If there's another unique column which has to be covered, you will only need to add it to the groupby.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer . Actually it worked for me in this way, 

df_work.groupby(['MONTH', 'STORECODE','GRP'], as_index=False)['VALUE'].sum()

Comment: Yeah, it does because you only had two unique values of GRP which were in the same position as the unique values of Month and StoreCode. Be carefull with what you need to  be unique or groupby will have a nondesirable behaviour.

Comment: Actually this was just a sample and it works for my big data